# Angular client side notifications based on data from websocket

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, socket.io

I have an Angular app that is displaying data from a mySQL database using socket.io and node.js

The goal of the app is to display any changes to the mySQL database and update in real time. It does this successfully.

Next I want to add an alert/notification section. I want this to display an alert if the values go above or below a certain point.

My problem is that I'm so new to angular I don't know the correct terminology for googling solutions! Anything I have found is related to pushing notifications to clients from the server. I want to be able to monitor the data and if it reaches a certain point trigger an event.

I'll give some background on how my socket functions.

In my node.js the socket emits an array of data with these fields.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    database.table('products')
        .withFields(['id', 'title', 'quantity', 'price'])
        .sort({id: -1})
        .getAll()
        .then(prods => {
            data = prods;
            io.sockets.emit('initial', {prods: [...data]});
            console.log("test")
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I have a socket.service that handles these emits

```
export class SocketService {

  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  getInitialData() {
    return this.createObserver('initial');
  }
  private createObserver(event: string) {
    return this.socket.fromEvent(event);
```

Then in my componenet.ts i subscribe to the service

```
constructor(private socketService: SocketService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  // local data is from socket.service.ts
  private subs: Subscription[] = [];
    localData: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subs.push(
      this.socketService.getInitialData().subscribe((data: ServerResponse) => {
        this.localData = data.prods;
      })
    );
```

In my component.html I display the data from the socket in a table

```
  <tr *ngFor="let d of localData">
          <td>{{ d.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.price }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.quantity }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Are there any means of having a notifications component that could monitor the value of say {{d.price}}
and triggering an event if it reaches a specific value. Also if it turns out that these values are just for observable purposes that's fine too. Maybe I'll have to rethink my approach and try from the server side.

Comment: Why can't you that in the component code you mentioned above. you can put a `if` block in the `subscribe` function achieve the same.

Also if you specifically want an event to be triggered you can use a Subject or EventEmitter do emit an the notification from the said if block.